# What is the difference between the knitR and knitR-ESS for polymode?

Tags: ess, polymode

I have recently setup polymode for use with Rnw and Rmd files.

When it came to knit/weave a document I was given the choice of four defaults;
knitR-ESS, Sweave, knitR and Sweave-ESS.

I usually use knitR outside of emacs but I wondered what is the difference/advantage/disadvantage of using knitR-ESS over knitR, if any, when knitting documents?

Thanks.

Comment: Although I haven't obtained a proper answer yet [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28324288/how-to-create-a-pdf-from-a-rmd-file-using-emacs-ess-pandoc-mode-and-polymode)  on  stackoverflow sheds some light on the question as it says that if you are using ESS, knitR-ESS will use the current *R* process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an active R process in your Emacs session, then the `knitr-ESS` weaver will use that process, as you've noted. That means any objects you create in your R chunks in your Rnw or Rmd document are available for interactive inspection (or even modification, although you most likely wouldn't want to do that) in the R buffer.

Comment: That is useful to know.